# in django i keep getting this ModuleNotFoundError: No module named receipts. everything else seems to be running fine

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, modulenotfounderror

i forked and cloned a gitlab repository. and it included a bunch of tests you
can run in terminal. All the test's pass except for test_feature_08.py
im not sure what else to do right now to get it to pass

[vscode directory layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruPRo.png)
receipts.views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from receipts.models import Receipt




@login_required
    def receipt_list(request):
    receipts = Receipt.objects.filter(purchaser=request.user)
    context = {
        "receipts": receipts,
    }
    return render(request, "receipts/list.html", context)



receipts.urls.py

from django.urls import path
from receipts.views import receipt_list




urlpatterns = [
    path("", receipt_list, name="home"),
]


expenses.urls.py



from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from django.shortcuts import redirect




def return_home(request):
    return redirect("home")


urlpatterns = [
    path("", return_home),
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("receipts/", include("receipts.urls")),
    path("accounts/", include("accounts.urls")),
]
                      

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tommyg/django-two-shot/receipts/views.py", line 3, in <module>
    from receipts.models import Receipt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'receipts'
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Add `"receipts",` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` list inside `settings.py` file.